how to set up pm2 auto-resurrect after server reboot for multiple users
We have multiple apps on a server that are handled by pm2.
Every dev has his own server account and we are all in a group that can use the same pm2 instance.
The pm2 folder is in a shared folder.
When I tried setting up auto-resurrect using "pm2 startup" the result didn't work and looking at the service status it is because it looked for the processes dump file (dump.pm2) in my own pm2 dir in my home folder instead of the shared pm2 dir.
Is there a way to set this up so after reboot the pm2 service looks for the dump file in the shared pm2 dir instead of my own?
